# Ampersands in Wordpress titles break my share to social media links

Tags: wordpress, post, twitter, ampersand

I was hoping to get some help with a bit of a coding problem that has been driving me crazy. I'd preferably like to write "&" instead of "and" in my wordpress post titles. But writing out ampersands breaks our post share links for twitter, facebook, and google-plus. Facebook is able to actually display the link (it takes the ampersand out of the title, though), but twitter full out fails, and google-plus as well.

This is the code for the share links:

```
<ul>
    <li class="video-twitter"><a target="_blank" href="http://twitter.com/share?text=<?php the_title(); ?>&amp;url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="Share on Twitter">Twitter</a></li>
    <li class="video-facebook"><a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php the_permalink();?>&t=<?php the_title(); ?>" title="Share on Facebook">Facebook</a></li>
    <li class="video-google"><a target="_blank" href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=<?php the_permalink();?>&t=<?php the_title(); ?>" title="Share on Google+">Google+</a></li>
</ul>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you add one of broken link url to understand what acutally happen there

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem today and it's rather easy to fix. All ampersands and such are served as entities by WordPress, this means if you use get_the_title() or the_title() ampersands are like this: & #038 ;

You can decode this using [html_entity_decode()](http://www.php.net/html_entity_decode) after that you'll have to make it URL friendly, which can be done using urlencode().

Combine them and you'll have this:

```
<?php print urlencode( html_entity_decode( get_the_title() ) ); ?>
```

Or do it the 'cleaner' way and create this function in your functions.php theme file:

```
function themeprefix_social_title( $title ) {
    $title = html_entity_decode( $title );
    $title = urlencode( $title );
    return $title;
}
```

This way you can call this function in your theme, which can be used for all social networks:

```
<?php print themeprefix_social_title( get_the_title() ); ?>
```

When applied to your example:

```
<ul>
    <li class="video-twitter"><a target="_blank" href="http://twitter.com/share?text=<?php print themeprefix_social_title( get_the_title() ); ?>&url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="Share on Twitter">Twitter</a></li>
    <li class="video-facebook"><a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php the_permalink();?>&t=<?php print themeprefix_social_title( get_the_title() ); ?>" title="Share on Facebook">Facebook</a></li>
    <li class="video-google"><a target="_blank" href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=<?php the_permalink();?>&t=<?php print themeprefix_social_title( get_the_title() ); ?>" title="Share on Google+">Google+</a></li>
</ul>
```